# Websocket angular e php

Tags: php, angularjs

Olá,
Tenho um websocket em php e uma factory em angular.
Preciso saber, quando existe, ou não, conexão com websocket, na parte do código o send, socket.send(JSON.stringify(data)); dessa factory

```
.factory('socket', [function ($rootScope) {
var wsUri = "ws://162.243.172.112:1234";//localhost:1234
try{
    var socket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    }catch(e){
        socket.onerror = function(ev){
            console.log(ev);
            alert("Falha");
        }
    }


return {
    send: function (data) {
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));

    },
    message: function(callback){
        socket.onmessage = function(ev) {
            var result = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
            //console.log(result);
            callback(result);

            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                $rootScope.mensagens=result;
            });

        };
    },

    error: function(callback){
        socket.onerror = function(ev){
            console.log(ev);
            alert("Falha");
        }
    }

};
```

}])

Comment: Seria ali no `}catch(e){`

Comment: É, mas não aparece nada no console, colocando console.log(e).
Só aparece uma mensagem, como:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://162.xxx.xxx/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFISED e aponta para a linha 91 do arquivo, que é: 
var socket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

Comment: Mas então eu não falei do console.log, eu falei que você tem que usar o `catch`, se entendi vc quer testar se o websocket funciona né? O catch é a solução, ae basta adicionar um `return;` dentro dele e criar uma função para usar o alternativo ao WS.

Comment: Certo @GuilhermeNascimento, mas quero que a minha app reconheça quando não há conexão, quando o websocket não está funcionando, para mandar um aviso para o usuário e não só alterar o WS. Pq se a conexão cair, tenho que reconectar o websocket e o usuário, entende? Não tenho um WS alternativo.

Comment: Entendi sim, então basta usar o `catch` e o o `socket.onerror` combinado com um callback para solicitar para o usuário isto. Eu não disse WS alternativo, falei qualquer coisa alternativa, tipo até uma mensagem de pedido é algo alternativo

Comment: Veja se é essa modificação, que fiz no código, aqui do post, está certa com relação ao que você disse.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, veja se o código está certo, agora.